# Django 1.10. Why does settings.LOGIN_URL default to /accounts/login/, while django.contrib.auth.urls uses ^login/$?

Tags: django, django-1.10

I'm migrating to Django 1.10 and trying to fix login issues.

So, going by [topics.auth.default Using the views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#id4)

I do the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

OK, and now I am getting a 404 about **/accounts/login** not existing.  Now, as this is an existing app I am moving to Django 1.10, I first figured I had forgotten that url somewhere.

But I couldn't find it.  Then it turns out that, in Django:

**django.conf.global_settings**:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

But, [Using the views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#id4), says:

> This will include the following URL patterns:
>       ^login/$ [name='login']

as expected from **django.contrib.auth.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
```

There is also some more guidance about watching what's in **settings.LOGIN_URL**.

Basically, the way I set up the url, it's expecting a login @ **/login/**.  But the settings default to **/accounts/login/**.

For, now, I've modified my settings to `LOGIN_URL = LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'`.  And I now have to deal with a template name error, which is expected, but at least I have gotten past the 404.

Wouldn't it have made more sense to suggest setting up the top-level **urls.py** as :

```
 url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Which would have lined up better with the settings default?  And also with the other guidance on that page, which repeatedly refers to `/accounts/xxx` for auth-related stuff.

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense I think. Feel free to [open a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket).

Comment: Learning Django at the moment and this has confused me too, I guess it's just an oversight.